# Probability of equality mod p

Tags: pr.probability

Consider two positive integers $x \ne y$  and let  $n = max\{\lfloor \log_2{x} \rfloor +1 ,\lfloor \log_2{y} \rfloor +1 \}$.  Choose a prime $p$ randomly from the first $3n$ primes.   What is the probability that $x \bmod p = y \bmod p$?

I believe it is at most $1/3$. My reasoning is that there are only $n$ primes at most for which $x \bmod p = y \bmod p$.  Does this make sense and is there a self contained proof?

I am interested in upper and lower bounds for this probability, especially those that hold for large $n$.

The same question is also at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567230/probability-of-equality-mod-p where an upper bound of $2/9$ is now conjectured.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be the number of primes divisors of $|y-x|$ among the $3n$ smallest primes; thus, your probability is $N/(3n)\le \omega(|y-x|)/(3n)$, where $\omega(x)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $x$. It is very easy to see, however, that $\omega(x)\le(1+o(1))\log x/\log\log x$. Taking into account that $|y-x|\le\exp(n)$, the probability in question is 
at most $(1/3+o(1))/\log n=o(1)$; hence, of course, smaller than $2/9$ or any other constant for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Do you think $2/9$ is in fact the least upper bound?

Comment: @Erhart: this is addresses in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant for the small $n$ case. Is the probability ever higher than $2/9$ and is that the lowest bounds that holds for all $x$ and $y$?  Thank you for your answer to the large $n$ question.

Comment: I didn't think much on the small $n$ case. With some effort, one can produce an explicit version of my estimate, and then check small values of $n$ with a computer.